# Cut text in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td class="sub">mmmmm</td><td class="sub">jjjjj</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="sub">lllll</td><td class="sub">wwwww</td></tr>
</table>

#tab td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 40px;
}

$(".sub").each(function(){
    var o = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(o.substring(0, 2))
})
```

LIVE EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/UTYLf/1/

i would like max-width for TD - 40px. i would like cut overflow text. I made substring but this is not usefriendly.
**mm** != **ll** and **jj** != **ww** etc. **mm** and **ll** has 2 chars, but **mm** takes more space than a **ll**.
In my example i would like have in table same as in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Eb6WN/

what I must use instead of `substr()`?
I can use HTML, CSS, JavaScript (jQuery) and PHP

Comment: Do you want `overflow: hidden` to the `td`s?

Comment: You can "hide" the overflow text, exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb6WN/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these types of situations I use `overflow: hidden` as well as adding a `title` for each cell to display the complete text:

```
#tab td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    max-width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

$(".sub").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).text()).css("cursor", "help");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hunter/UTYLf/4/

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) (`text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`) should sort you out, I think...

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the `text-overflow` property to your first CSS class.

```
#tab td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 40px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Some documentation about `text-overflow` can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Comment: Some better, non-W3S, documentation [can be found here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html). [Say NO to W3Schools.](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `overflow: hidden;` for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a jQuery plugin that allows to have this multiline
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis